# cordova plugin dependencies not in npm registry

Tags: javascript, cordova, github, npm

I am developing a cordova application and i want to perform whitesource code scan for cordova application to overcome some license issues

You can get more about the whitesource in this link http://docs.whitesourcesoftware.com/display/serviceDocs/NPM+Plugin

The problem with my cordova application is i installed plugins from the internet but the plugins are not getting recognized when i am doing npm install from the package json

Now i cant perform whitesource without all the packages in node module.

How to make these plugins get install

For example one error

```
  npm ERR! code E404
  npm ERR! 404 Not Found: 
 com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.streamingmedia@~0.1.4
```

The above plugin is used for streaming purpose in which i installed from this location but i am getting error when i am performing npm install

```
  [https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media][1]
```

how to ensure that cordova plugins are installed when we do npm

[plugin](https://github.com/nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media)-streaming-media

Comment: Try `npm i nchutchind/cordova-plugin-streaming-media --save`